# WPF. Change DataContext on event binding to access code-behind on a MVVM project

Tags: wpf, mvvm, code-behind, datacontext

i'm developing a WPF application with MVVM.
At the XAML code i have a Grid with its DataContext pointing to a ViewModel, and i need to know if it is possible to change the DataContext at runtime to access an event at its code-behind.

Code-behind for the view:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ValidationEvent(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        //Something useful
    }
}
```

Here is the code that i tried in XAML:

```
<Grid Validation.Error={Binding Path=ValidationEvent RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}/>
```

The XAML code throws an XamlParseException telling that it is not possible to do the Binding on an "AddErrorHandler", that it is only possible for a DependencyProperty on a DependencyObject.

I don't want to change the DataContext of the Grid because inside it there are elements that access the MainViewModel properties, so i just want to change the DataContext for the Validation.Error event binding... If it is possible...

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do inside that event handler and why cannot it be handled in the view model ?

Comment: Just testing (that's why the event is empty). Yes, It could be handled at the ViewModel, but because it is an event, i cannot bind it directly to an ICommand, i had to use something like MVVM Light's "EventToCommand", and i want to know if it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: A binding is used to tell WPF where to go to obtain a value. You can change the Source of the binding to tell it should go somewhere other than the current DataContext to obtain the value, as you have in your code by using `RelativeSource Self` to change the source for that binding to the Grid object itself. You could change it to be the MainWindow object instead (I'd recommend either using `ElementName`, or a `RelativeSource` of `x:Type Window`), however that won't change the two core problem here - Events do not know how to read a binding, and ValidationEvent is a method, not a property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Validation.Error` is an event, not a property. You can't set Bindings to events.

You can use things like MVVM Light's `EventToCommand`, or Microsoft's own Interactivity `EventTrigger` to associate Commands to Events.

But there really isn't anything wrong with just adding a regular event handler in code-behind and calling some viewmodel code from there... Contrary to what many people seem to think, MVVM doesn't forbid the use of code-behind and what you'd be doing is not very different from what an EventToCommand or an EventTrigger are doing under the hood.

First of all, just set the event handler name for the `Validation.Error` event.

```
<Grid Validation.Error="ValidationEvent" />
```

And then in your code-behind do whatever you want.

```
private void ValidationEvent(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
{
    // Something useful

    // Some call to VM code
    (this.DataContext as MainViewModel).SomeMethod();
}
```

This works independently of your DataContext (as long as you cast `this.DataContext` to the correct type, of course).

Event handlers don't depend on your DataContext, only Bindings do.

Comment: Could you please explain it further? Do you mean not to bind the DataContext of the View to the ViewModel and call the ViewModel from the Code-Behind?

Comment: I think we're mixing up things here. Event handling and DataBinding are two completely different things. You don't need to change your DataContext to handle events in code-behind, events are always handled in code-behind, no matter what your DataContext is.